# ng-src image disappearing during ng-repeat on new refresh of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in data" ng-click="select(x);">
<td><img ng-src="{{ isSelected(x) ? selectedImg : nonSelectedImg }}"</td>
<td>... Contents ...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

isSelected just checks 'x' against the x given to select();

I have a function that runs every 10 seconds to update the array 'data', doing this:

```
$scope.data = response.data
```

After clicking a row I want the image selectedImg to stay when the array refreshes, but it disappears on each update. I'm aware that the documentaton says "ngRepeat uses $watchCollection to detect changes in the collection. When a change happens, ngRepeat then makes changes to the DOM."

What can I do to keep selectedImg on the page?

Comment: Well, you're stating you would like selectedImg to stay visible, is `isSelected(x)` resolving true every time then? I don't know what x looks like each time, but is it the same object that was originally selected?

Comment: Also something else that alarms me, is you shouldn't alter a `$scope` *array* variable by assignment. Rather, perform a `$scope.data.splice(0)` to empty the array, then push each element onto the `$scope.data` array. I read somewhere if you simply overwrite the array it can have adverse affects and in most cases decouple the binding.

Comment: @GONeale, `isSelected(x)` resolves true for that x until another row has been clicked. I tried what you said, 
`$scope.data.splice(0);
                for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.data.push(response.data[i]);
                }` but the problem persists

Comment: You know what, the solution was actually really easy... I was comparing object-to-object but there is a unique key inside the object that I could compare instead, and changing the comparison to the two objects' keys made it work properly. I still find it weird that it didn't work properly when comparing objects because they were still identical.

Comment: Ah, that will do it :)

Comment: Coming back to this. "Same" Objects aren't equal to each other. CS101... doh